# find method not working on RxJs Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm using NgRx in my angular2 application. However, I'm having some difficulty using the find method on my Observable.

The translations for my application are coming from an external application via rest and are stored in the NGRX store as a key value object. This object has a key variable with the code, and a translation variable.

When I try to implement the find method to find the correct translation object, it doesn't work.

```
@Pipe({


name: 'translate',
})
export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform, OnInit {

  uiMessages$ = this.sb.uiMessages$;

  constructor (private sb: AppSandbox) {}

  transform(value: string, args: any[]): any {
    return this.uiMessages$.find((uiMessage: UiMessage) => (uiMessage.key === value)).translation;
  }
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `uiMessages$` is an Observable, you cannot just use `.find` and expect an object, as `find` is an rxjs-operator and rxjs-operators will always return an Observable.

What you could do is:

```
transform(value: string, args: any[]): any {
    return this.uiMessages$
        .switchMap((uiMessages: UiMessage[]) => Observable.from(uiMessages))
        .find((uiMessage: UiMessage) => (uiMessage.key === value))
        .map((uiMessage: UiMessage) => uiMessage.translation);
}
```

and then use the `async`-pipe additionally:

```
<div>{{'foo' | translate | async}}</div>
```

Comment: I understand, however I get the error property find does not exist on type 'Observable<UiMessage[]>'. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that is basically what I explained in my answer: `.find` will return return an Observable, if you want to map that to a plain object(or string) you will have to either go through `async` pipe (which is the safest way btw.) or implement some kind of syncronouse readout (which is extremely ugly), which would only be possible if you can be 100% certain that `uiMessages$` contains no async flows

Comment: Just as a side-note, there ready-to-use solutions for translation-handling in angular2, just in case that is what you want to accomplish: https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate

Comment: I have implemented it the way you said, but my intelliJ shows the error described in my comment on the find method in the transform method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what would the import for find be? If I use import 'rxjs/add/operator/find'; the error changes to 'The argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the usage.' @olsn

Comment: have you tried setting the type explicitly yet? like `.find<UiMessage>(...)` ?

Comment: I'm getting closer but I'm getting new error's I do not understand. The method is like this now: `transform(value: string, args: any[]): any {
    return this.uiMessages$
      .find<UiMessage>((uiMessage: UiMessage) => (uiMessage.key === value))
      .map((uiMessage: UiMessage) => uiMessage.translation);
  }` The error however is the following: TS2684: The 'this' context of type 'Observable<UiMessage[]>' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<UiMessage>'

Comment: So adjust the code according to the error-message. I edited my answer, that should resolve your issue - from your code it was not apparent that your `uiMessages$` was an `Observable<UiMessage[]>` - you should always type your Observables at least when providing code on SO as this is not something one can guess from your provided code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the type after the find. It should look something like this

```
transform(value: string, args: any[]): any {
    return this.uiMessages$.find<UiMessage>(uiMessage => (uiMessage.key === value)).translation;
}
```